# how to stop a flink window job over a data stream?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, sliding-window, flink-cep

I have a program in which a producer creates events and send them to a Kafka topic. Then, I create a data stream over this topic and a flink sliding window process this data stream. In case the number of events in each window goes below a threshold, the program needs to change the producer to another one. Now, when this happen, I want to stop this flink window job in the code and start a new window over the same data stream which now consumes events from the new producer.
My code is as below:

```
dataStream
.windowAll(SlidingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(window_size), Time.seconds(1)))
.process(new ProcessAllWindowFunction<DataEvent, String, TimeWindow>() {
@Override
public void process(Context context, Iterable<DataEvent> input,
Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
   int count = 0;
   for (DataEvent de : input) {
     count++;
   }
   if (Controller.offset < query.getDuration()) {
      out.collect("Window: " + context.window() + "count: " + count);
      if (Controller.offset > window_size){
         //do something
      }
   }
}
}
});
```

If I stop the producer to not send the data to the Kafka topic, I receive this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform operation after producer has been closed
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.throwIfProducerClosed(KafkaProducer.java:896)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:905)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:889)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:775)
    at FlinkCEP01.Producer.producerStart(Producer.java:235)
    at FlinkCEP01.Controller$1.doInBackground(Controller.java:262)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My question is how can I stop the window analysis over the data stream?

Comment: Where is your `producerStart` method? Also, I don't think Flink will work well within a Swing application

Comment: The requirements aren't clear. Must you dynamically introduce a new Producer (hard to imagine why), or are you switching between a couple of pre-determined Producers, or it is instead that you need to start writing to a brand new topic, or are you switching between a set of predetermined topics?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I checked the code again and found that I should not close the producer, since I need to use it again. That's why I receive this error.

Comment: @DavidAnderson in my scenario, I have a set of sensors which are my producers. In the runtime, the availability of these sensors may change, some of them may disconnect or reconnect and some new sensors may be added to the system. So, I need dynamic set of producers. At the start of execution, I create several producers and switch between them in the runtime. One of them is selected at the moment and the selected producer sends data to a predefined topic. when switching the producer, I need to reset window for the new producer, stop all the previous windows, start new windows. how to do that?

Comment: You can use one producer instance for multiple topics. You don't need Flink to produce data  though